# Birth problem solving

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

A girl named Rima was born in 2012 and died in 2013, but she was alive 40 years 2 months.

How is it possible?

Comment: "A girl name Rima" -> "A girl name**d** Rima"?

Comment: That would make me sad.  The extraneous details (name, duration specified down to months) were making me hope there was a little more substance to this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer:

> **2012** and **2013** are hospital room numbers. 
> She was born in `room number` 2012 and died in `room number` 2013.

Answer (score 4):

> Rima is a female mouse.  A mouse-year is equal to 20 human years.
>
> We're told that Rima lived to an age of 10 mouse-years and 2 mouse-months, so that's equivalent to (`((10*12)+2)/20`) about 6 human months, which would result in a death in 2013, if the birth was in the latter half of 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm

> She was born on 20:12, and died 10 years 2 months and 1 minute later on 20:13

Answer (score 1):

> Rima was legally dead for a few minutes when she was 1 year old, but was then resuscitated.  Thus, while she technically died a year after she was born, she then went on to live a happy and cherished life for a further nine years and change.
>
> Ordinarily, I'd insert a joke or a wry comment here, but honestly the whole thing is too tragic.  :(

Answer (score 1):

> Rima is a fictional character (form a webcomic, a novel, a tv show...)

So it could be

> a webcomic that lasted for 10 years and 2 months, and is set between 2012 and 2013

or

> a tv show that aired in 2012-2013, and focuses on 10 years and 2 months of her life.

Comment: I thought about this one, and couldn't find a character named Rima other than DC's [Rima: The Jungle Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rima), who could be argued to have been born in 1974 and died in 1975 (which is the period in which she had her own comic series).  Doesn't match the years we have been given, though..  Not sure what the "10 years 2 months" would be referring to, either.  But that's an awfully specific duration that's presumably either very important or a particularly annoying scarlet herring.

Answer (score 0):

> Rima is a time traveller.
>  She was born 2012 and at some point between now and 2022 someone invented time travel.
>  
>  When Rima was about 10 years 2 months old she traveled back in time to 2013 where she died.

Answer (score 0):

Could Rima be born on another planet like Jupiter?

> as one year on Jupiter is almost 12 years on Earth, we could believe that when Rima was born in 2012 (Jupiter year) and then died in 2013 (Jupiter year), she could be aged maximum 12 (earth time), so if she spent only few jupiter months alived (around 10), she could be aged 10 earth years (and also 2 earth months)

Comment: I'd go for Venus over Jupiter. There's no such thing as "Jupiter 2012", but there is such a thing as "a Venus year". However, the ratio of an earth year to a Venus year is 1:1.6 not 1:12.

Answer (score -3):

> two Rimas, a 1 year old and a 10 year old